# Is Endogeneity an assumption of Ensemble Methods?

Tags: regression, correlation, multiple-regression, ensemble-learning, endogeneity

I am using catboost regressor and lgbm regressor to perform regression on dataset. I want to know the assumptions of both the models. Where can I find assumptions for both the models?

Next I want to know if I should care about endogeneity when using Catboost or LGBM? Or is it just applicable to linear regression? References to papers would be help understand better.

Comment: In gradient boosting, you optimize a cost function that, in most cases, can be translated to an equivalent maximum likelihood problem, which entails a distributional assumption. However, machine learning has a different point-of-view compared to statistics: assumptions can be ignored if you get the performance you want.

Comment: @Firebug so if I understand correctly when applying gradient boosting we really shouldn't worry about endogeneity or for that matter any of the assumptions as weights are assigned by optimizing cost function and not MLE.

Comment: If you do care about the science behind your data-generating process, and if you are not concerned with issues of causality, and if you are not concerned with scientific inference, and if you are not concerned with generalization, and if you don't care to provide accuracy bounds for your predictions, and if you are not concerned about optimal predictions, then sure, feel free to ignore each and every assumption.